# clsss within class , null reference exception, C#

Tags: c#

My class looks like this.

```
public class LogSettings
{
    public string attributeName { get; set; }//TODO: change the variable name

    public Warnings[] warnings = new Warnings[3];
}

public class Warnings
{
   public string typeOfWarning {get; set;}

    public bool isAbsolute { get; set; }

    public decimal numUpDownValue { get; set; }

    public LogSettingActions[] actionItems = new LogSettingActions[10];
}

public class LogSettingActions
{
    public string actionItem{ get; set;}
}
```

but when I try to create Warnings instance it throws NullReference error.

```
var rows = FindChilds<ctlLogConfigRow>(lvLogConfigTemplate);
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    LogSettings instance = new LogSettings();
    instance.attributeName = row.GroupHeaderText;

    var allWarnings = FindChilds<ctlWarnings>(row);

    for (int i = 0; i < allWarnings.Count; i++)
    {

       instance.warnings[i].typeOfWarning = allWarnings[i].ctlWarningGroupBoxFixedHeader1.Header.ToString();//It throws error here
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Where is the error? What line?

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Which reference is `null`?

Comment: What is null? `instance`? `warnings[i]`? `allWarnings[i]`? `ctlWarningGroupBoxFixedHeader1`? `Header`? You need to give more info than this...

Comment: You need to add a lot more null-checking. The reason you're getting a null reference exception is because something is actually null.

Comment: you're not creating a new instance, you're assigning a typeOfWarning value on the object but its not created

Comment: Are you sure that instance.warnings[i] is instantiated?

Comment: What version of .NET is this?  Who still uses arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LogSettings.warnings` is initialized as an array, but the array elements are not initialized.

Consider initialing the array items in the LogSettings constructor:

```
public class LogSettings
{
    public LogSettings()
    {
         warnings = new Warnings[3];
         for (int i=0; i<warnings.Length; i++)
         {
              warnings[i] = new Warnings();
         }
    }

    public string attributeName { get; set; }//TODO: change the variable name

    public Warnings[] warnings;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line doesn't create any Warnings objects:

```
public Warnings[] warnings = new Warnings[3];
```

All the references in the array are initialized to null. You need to actually create some objects first before you try to access any properties on those objects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < warnings.Length; ++i) {
    warnings[i] = new Warnings();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
public Warnings[] warnings = new Warnings[3];
```

You create an array with space for 3 Warnings object (or rather references to them). It doesn't actually create the Warnings. After this line Warnings[0] is null, as are all the others.

Comment: @user781700: Tried what before? I was telling you what you did wrong. I left it to you to figure out how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

In the LogSettings you initialize the warnings array, but not the eleemnts of the array. You need to initialize each of the elements.

```
 for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
     warning[i] = new Warning();
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
public Warnings[] warnings = new Warnings[3];
```

only creates the array, not the objects in the array. To create instances of `Warnings` in the array, do this:

```
public Warnings[] warnings = 
    Enumerable.Repeat<Warnings>(new Warnings(), 3).ToArray();
```

and same with:

```
public LogSettingActions[] actionItems = 
    Enumerable.Repeat<LogSettingActions>(new LogSettingActions(), 10).ToArray();
```

Gotta love LINQ.